# Adding support for language on a code fence block

Tags: doxygen

doxygen has support for code fence blocks that also have syntax highlighting in the output.

Here is the documentation:
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_fenced

It looks like this:

```
~~~{.c}
int somefunc(int somevar);
~~~
```

I want to support .sql;  I tried it, but it did not highlight.

My two questions are:

1. How do I determine what code types doxygen supports for code fence blocks?
2. Is there some way to define a new one?  I am quite happy with just a keyword highlighter; it does not need to be a full parse.

Comment: The languages supported for codeblocks are the same languages doxygen can parse: C, Objective-C, C#, PHP, Java, Python, IDL (Corba, Microsoft, and UNO/OpenOffice flavors), Fortran, VHDL, Tcl, and to some extent D. 

The only language I think ontop of that that doxygen doesn't parse but can generate code blocks for is XML. To add an SQL version would require to write a new doxygen 'parser' similar to the XML one.

Other than that there is no quick way to add a new language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment, I have looked into adding SQL syntax highlighting to fenced code blocks and \code blocks.

It should now be available if you build from source at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen or it will be available in the next version (1.8.13).

Here is an example of the syntax highlighting:

[image: sql syntax highlighting]

If you could test it before the next release, that would be nice, as well.

Comment: Wow, that is awesome.  Only problem is that I am doing this work on a client computer that I cannot compile on.  It is a windows 7 box.  Do you have a donation link?  I would like to show my appreciation with a donation.